# Como paginar o método IAmazonS3.ListObjects?

Tags: c#, amazon-aws

O método `IAmazonS3.ListObjects` que vocês podem conferir [aqui](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MIS3ListObjectsListObjectsRequest.html) limita o retorno em 1000 itens por requisição porém não informa se é possível fazer paginação, tenho buckets  com mais de 10 milhões de arquivos e preciso percorrer cada um deles. A descrição do método em português é essa:

> Retorna alguns ou todos (no máximo 1000) dos objetos em um bucket. Você pode usar parametros de requisição como um critério de seleção para retornar um conjunto de objetos em um bucket

É possível paginar essa requisição? não encontrei nada no Google nem na documentação.

Minha função é essa:

```
static ListObjectsResponse GetBucketObjects(string bucketName)
{
  ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();  
  request.BucketName = bucketName;
  request.MaxKeys = 1000; //Mesmo que eu coloque 90000000000, o sistema considera 1000 
  ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a [documentação do `SDK` para `JavaScript`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property), você tem de conhecer o `NextMarker` para que a consulta retorne os dados posteriores a um determinado resultado.

Desta forma, não é possivel consultar por um pagina especifica sem ter consultado a anterior previamente.

Segue um exemplo em JS.:

```
var params = {
    Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE',
    MaxKeys: 500
}

var listObjects = function (params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
    })
}

async function GetBucketObjects () {
    var data = null;
    do
    {
        var data = await listObjects(params)
        // faça algo com data.Contents
        params.Marker = data.NextMarker
    } while (data.IsTruncated)
}

GetBucketObjects('')
```

Segue um esboço da versão em C# (não testei)

```
var listResponse = default(ListObjectsResponse);
var listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
{
    BucketName = "STRING_VALUE",
    MaxKeys = 500
};    

do
{

    listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
    // faça algo com listResponse.S3Objects
    listRequest.Marker = listResponse.NextMarker;
} while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
```